# Device or resource busy when deleting Youtube folder from /data/app

Tags: delete

I am trying to delete my /data/app/com.google.android.youtube-DVUYe6iX9r5J1nYk8PlC2w== folder to fix the bug described [here](https://github.com/YTVanced/VancedManager/issues/322); however, I keep getting a "Device or resource busy" message. I tried using this command

```
adb pull /data/adb/service.d/vanced.sh > %UserProfile%\Desktop\vanced.sh
```

and also Total Commander file manager but received the same error. How can I delete the folder?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: A reboot has a good chance to solve this resource busy thing - do the deletion before starting youtube. But as Andrew suggests, probably you have simply no permission to delete that folder without rooting.

Comment: Yes. I am rooted with Magisk. I tried deleting it as soon as I rebooted but same problem.

Comment: Checking with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck also confirmed I had root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Vanced-related files in `/data/adb` and `/data/adb/service.d` operating on the Youtube folder hence it being busy. The solution was to delete all of these files, reboot, then delete the Youtube folder. It seems the Vanced contributor failed to realize this and instructed me to delete the Youtube folder while Vanced was still operating on it.